# Android Images cache categories. How to make them?

Tags: android, caching, image-loading

I have an App where I load user data from server and cache it. Also I have separate images for some sort of catalog, images for user created content etc.

There is types of images that needs to be downloaded and being cached all the time, and there is images that should be cached temporary for like day or two.

So I have 2-3 categories of images total. To achieve it I extended  **UniveralImageLoader** and made several instances with different caches.

Problem is, that  UniveralImageLoader is no longer maintained and has major flaw with `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException`.

**Since I wrote a lot of bs above I simplify my question**

How to implement separate caches with different rules in non `UIL` image loading library (Glide or Fresco for example)?

Answer (score 0):

All this libraries use App inner place for cache. Some of them allows to add properties to/after init() method, so you can set place to save images.

I set such place for Picasso:

`public static File getCacheFolder() {
        File path = SystemInfoUtil.isWriteExternalStoragePermissionGranted() ?
                new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                         Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "App Name") :
                Application.getContext().getExternalCacheDir();
        path.mkdirs();
        return path;
    }`

Comment: But how to have two instances of Picasso at same time configured with different cache folders?